# jquery facebook share button dynamic url insert

Tags: jquery, facebook, url, dynamic, share-button

with `var url = window.location.href;` get i my url and now i will the url variable put in the facebook share link.

```
<fb:share-button href="url variable here" type="button"></fb:share-button>
```

how can I implement that?

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go!

```
var url = window.location.href;
$('fb\\:share-button').attr('href', url)
```

Hope this helps